Do you separate grounds and neutrals main box?
do you need to separate the grounds and neutrals in main box when adding a subpanel? what about just ground subpanel in same wall as main box with ground from main not from outside rod?

Please tell us what country you are in and if possible, a photo would hep.

Is the subpanel in the same building as the main panel?

The main/first is the only place where grounds and neutrals are bonded together.  If you have a meter outside with a panel with a few breakers, that is your main panel.  The big panel inside will be a sub panel.
Sub panels in other buildings not attached to the house need the ground wire back to the inside panel plus ground rods.
Sub panels in the same house or an attached garage/building do not need ground rods.
This is for the U.S. and Canada.
